# Why I cannot override the OnWindowCreated and I don't get to see the ShowOnKeyBoardInput property?

Tags: c#, xaml, microsoft-metro

```
 protected override void OnWindowCreated(WindowCreatedEventArgs args)
    {
        // Register QuerySubmitted handler for the window at window creation time and only registered once
        // so that the app can receive user queries at any time.
        SearchPane.GetForCurrentView().QuerySubmitted += new TypedEventHandler<SearchPane, SearchPaneQuerySubmittedEventArgs>(OnQuerySubmitted);
    }
```

Can't seem to override onWindowCreated I don't even see it on the override intellisense of the App.xaml.cs. Am I missing something here? I downloaded a sample Search Contract application. Anyone knows what I'm missing?

Even this part is missing

```
        SearchPane.GetForCurrentView().ShowOnKeyboardInput = true;
        SearchPane.GetForCurrentView().ShowOnKeyboardInput = false;
```

ShowOnKeyboardInput doesn't exist.

Why I cannot **override the OnWindowCreated** and I don't get to see the **ShowOnKeyBoardInput property**?

UPDATE: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Search-app-contract-sample-118a92f5/view/Discussions

Comment: Leo, can you change this item's title to be in question form? What exactly is the problem... can't override OnWindowCreated?

Comment: I'm having the same problem with the App settings sample demo. Did you managed to resolve this?

Comment: I've found the solution. Please see my Answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out what was the problem.

The OnWindowCreated method was implemented in Windows 8 RTM release. So if you are still getting this problem upgrade your Windows.

Comment: Seems legit, I haven't upgrade my Windows.

Answer (score 0):

App.xaml is not a window and does not inherit from Window. You would need to place this code in a window for it to work.

EDIT: actually nothing in the framework has an OnWindowCreated override that I can see. Is this sample for C# at all? Can you post a link to the sample?

Comment: I know that. Check the MSDN Documentation and this is Windows 8.

Comment: @LeoLuis ok, this is for VS2012 and I presume .net 4.5 are you using these?

Comment: Yup. I am on Windows 8/VS 2012

Comment: @LeoLuis I haven't used it yet, do you have to select .net 4.5? Is it currently on 4.0?